# Compare lists with Linq, select records where ID appears in just one list

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to Linq and am tryng to filter records from two lists based on a field.
Each list has an ID, I want to take any record where the ID appears in one list but not the other.
I was able to do this with just a list of the ID's as follows:

```
List1 = _class1.getList1();
List2 = _class2.getList2();
```

(for introduction purposes I am using a class I would like to get rid of that has a list of the data and also a list of just the ID's, I should be able to do this with just the list of data though in two statements comparing list1 to list2 and vice versa)

```
var inList1ButNot2 = List1.IDList.Except(List2.IDList);
var inList2ButNot1 = List2.IDList.Except(List1.IDList);
```

Where I'm running into trouble is using the data list getting the comparison of the second list's ID field. I believe it should be something like:

```
var inList1ButNot2 = DataList1.Select(x => x.ID)
        .Except(DataList2.Select(y => y.ID));
```

The problem with that is that I'm not getting the entire record just the field I am comparing, do I need to individually select each field afterwards or is there a way in the statement to select the record if ID appears in one list but not the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you really want here is an `ExceptBy` method; you want to be able to perform an `Except` on a projection of each element, rather than on the element iteself.  Here is an implementation of such a method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    IEnumerable<TSource> other,
    Func<TSource, TKey> selector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;

    var set = new HashSet<TKey>(other.Select(selector), comparer);

    foreach (var item in source)
        if (set.Add(selector(item)))
            yield return item;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
var inList1ButNot2 = DataList1.ExceptBy(DataList2, item => item.ID);
var inList2ButNot1 = DataList2.ExceptBy(DataList1, item => item.ID);
```

Comment: It might be simpler to write a custom equality comparer for the [out-of-the-box method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx).

Comment: @Rawling If you only need to do this once then yes, that would probably be the case, but I find this method useful enough that the up-front cost of writing this method is a net savings in time as it means each future solution to this problem can be done with a method call and a lambda rather than a new named class that takes up half a screen and several minutes of just typing.

Comment: Good point, and I've come up with a reusable solution that also doesn't require you to rewrite any of the other set operations you might want to use, or to update your rewrites if the out-of-the-box methods get improved down the line.

Comment: @Rawling I'm aware of it; I've used it before in a number of places (even in other SO answers) but it does have it's problems as well.  Both are useful tools.

Comment: Fair enough, it's obvious enough I wouldn't have expected you not to be aware of it :)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, think this may be a little over my head but seemed to work. This is a project in VS2008 so parameters can't have default values so I moved the comparer into the method body and the results look good so far.

Comment: @user2219738 If you don't need the comparer at all you can just remove the parameter completely (it's not used in this case).  If you want to maintain that functionality you can do so with two overloads, one with the extra parameter and one with that calls the other.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way to do this, but:

```
var inList1ButNot2 = DataList1.Where(x => !(DataList2.Any(y => y.ID == x.ID)));
```

NB: I free-handed that, so there may be a typo.

Comment: Note that this is doing a linear search of the other set for each item in the first, unlike `Except` which is able to use a hash based structure to do the checks *much* quicker.

Comment: I would be interested to know why someone chose to down-vote this answer. @Servy made a good point, but it does not mean that the answer I provided was incorrect or otherwise deficient.

Comment: Perhaps not surprisingly, I would prefer the solution I provided over the accepted solution -- I judge it to be simpler and clearer -- unless I was concerned that performance was going to be an issue in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var list1 = new List<Asd>();
        var list2 = new List<Asd>();

        var asd = new Asd() {Id = 1, Name = "asd"};
        var asd2 = new Asd() {Id = 2, Name = "asd"};
        var asd3 = new Asd() {Id = 3, Name = "asd"};
        var asd4 = new Asd() {Id = 4, Name = "asd"};
        var asd5 = new Asd() {Id = 5, Name = "asd"};

        list1.Add(asd);
        list1.Add(asd2);
        list1.Add(asd3);

        list2.Add(asd);
        list2.Add(asd4);
        list2.Add(asd5);

        var onlyInFirstList = list1.Where(x => !list2.Any(y => y == x));
        var onlyInSecondList = list2.Where(x => !list1.Any(y => y == x));
```

This should work, not perfect but working :)

Comment: Note that this is doing a linear search of the other set for each item in the first, unlike `Except` which is able to use a hash based structure to do the checks *much* quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this.

```
public void Test(List<List1> list1, List<List2> list2)
{
    var result = from l1 in list1
                 where list2.All(l2 => l1.Id != l2.Id)
                 select l1;

}
```

Or, if you have properties from both (I'm assuming they're different types?) you could return an anonymous type and also bring back properties from the callers instance

```
public void Test(List<List1> list1, List<List2> list2)
{
    var result = from l1 in list1
                 where list2.All(l2 => l1.Id != l2.Id)
                 select new
                 {
                     l1.Id,
                     l1.OtherField1,
                     Test = 10.5, //Example declare new field
                     SomethingElse = this.PropertyXyz; //Set new field = instance property
                 };

}
```

Comment: Note that this is doing a linear search of the other set for each item in the first, unlike `Except` which is able to use a hash based structure to do the checks *much* quicker.

Comment: That's interesting, and I think calls for me to do more research.

I had always read that each method call in Linq essentially double the pushes on the stack as it evaluates the statement, plus an additional call for each lambda created.

I think I'm going to have to build out some tests to really see the performance ramifications, can you point me to some documentation?

Comment: It's not terribly important to think about particularly low level details.  Imagine how `All` is going to be implemented.  It's going to go through each item in the source sequence and perform the provided method on each item.  Think what `where` does.  It goes through each item in the source sequence and calls the given predicate on each item.  You go through each item in list1 through `Where`, and for each item you go through each item in `list2` in `All`.  It's effectively two nested `foreach` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rewrite the logic in `Except` (and all the other set operations), but allowing for something that can be reused for other classes and selectors, consider something like the following:

```
private class LambdaComparer<T, U> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private Func<T, U> selector;

    public LambdaComparer(Func<T, U> selector)
    {
        this.selector = selector;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return EqualityComparer<U>.Default.Equals(selector(x), selector(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 0;
        return EqualityComparer<U>.Default.GetHashCode(selector(obj));
    }
}

var inList1ButNot2 = List1.IDList.Except(
    List2.IDList,
    new LambdaComparer<ClassWithID, int>(w => w.ID));
```

Comment: Note that in this case you're calling the selector on each item multiple times in *most* cases (not just occasionally).  This is unlikely to be a problem when just getting a simple property, as is the case here, but if the lambda has side effects, is expensive to run, or doesn't generate identical results each time it's called, then it's a *big* problem.

Comment: Oh, and a common addition to this type is to pass in an optional equality comparer for the key (which if you were suitably motivated you could even chain with another instance of this class) instead of exclusively using the default comparer.  You can also create a static `Create` method to allow the second generic argument to be inferred from the lambda.

Comment: @Servy Good points about the multiple selector calls, and the inferring via static method... I did at least think of the optional comparer but couldn't be bothered to write it out! I'm not sure chaining them would be much use, though, you may as well just include the logic in the first lambda.

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like this

```
list1 = list1.Union(list2).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: 1) `Union` will already ensure only distinct values in the result, there is no need to call `Distinct`.  2) This isn't comparing the `ID` fields; you'd need to pass in a custom comparer to do that 3) He doesn't want to get the `Union`, he wants one `Except` the other (but comparing the ID).  This doesn't generate those results (even if you did add the custom comparer).